# Adding an extra ground bar to my main service panel

Tags: wiring

when installing an extra ground bar or bars to back of main service panel. Are the screws all that is needed for grounding or is more to be done.

Comment: What make and model is your panel, and what ground bar kit are you trying to fit to it?

Comment: "needed" and "best practice, which my be more than 'needed' " are different standards. Mine are connected to each other with heavy wires as well - by my electrician, but I approve of it.

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. Unfortunately, we'll need more info before we have any chance of helping you. Please [take our tour](//diy.stackexchange.com/tour) so you'll know how best to participate here.